# Change background color on hover

Tags: html, css

When I am trying to changing the bg color in "a:hover", its not completely filling the old background-color. What should I do for this in css?

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ORDER</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CAREERS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**css**

```
header nav ul {
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
header nav ul li {
    float:left;
    background-color:#018343;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:40px 5px 0 0;
    padding:5px;
    padding-right:10px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:"Arial";
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:16px;
    border-radius:6px 0px 6px 0px;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    text-shadow:1px 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color:#ff9000;
}
header nav ul li a {
    color:#ff9000;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
header nav ul li a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#010101;
}
```

Comment: whre is your html and css source code? and please resend upload image.

Comment: or even better a fiddle?

Comment: perhaps the old background-color you're seeing is from another element and not the from the link?

Comment: @MightyPork Code in the question is more important than a fiddle.

Comment: <nav>

<ul>

<li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ORDER</a></li>
<li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
<li><a href="#">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CAREERS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>

</ul>

</nav>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2EM23/3/)

**CSS**

```
.header nav ul {
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.header nav ul li {
    float:left;
    background-color:#018343;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:40px 5px 0 0;
    padding:5px;
    padding-right:10px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:"Arial";
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:16px;
    border-radius:6px 0px 6px 0px;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    text-shadow:1px 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color:#ff9000;
}
.header nav ul li a {
    color:#ff9000;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.header nav ul li:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#010101;
}
```

Comment: I have given both HTML and css now....plz chk and tell me

Comment: check now i have update my answer

Comment: @Fags, you will still need to add `nav ul li:hover a{ color:#fff; }` for the text to be white.

Comment: @Ravindra Here is a [working solution](http://jsbin.com/ubowuk/1/edit), in this case you should add `transition` to `li` elements.